# is there a way to get month name by giving an integer value PHP

Tags: php

hi i am using PHP i want to pass an integer value (1-12) and get corresponding month name , is there a way in PHP to do that or i have to do t my own by initialize a month names array.

i want to do like

```
$month_name = get_month_name(1);

echo $month_name ; //echo january
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
echo date('F', strtotime("2012-$int-01"));
```

Comment: Simple and easy to implement!

Answer (score 5):

Another built in way would be

```
$monthInt = 3;
$monthName = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $monthInt)->format('F');
```

I would be nice if PHP had a built in way of getting date names without creating a date object.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to get month name by giving an integer value PHP

```
  <?php
  function get_month_name($inp)
  {
  return date("F", strtotime(date("d-$inp-y")));
  }
  $month_name = get_month_name("1");
  echo $month_name;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function get_month_name($month)
{
    $months = array(
        1   =>  'January',
        2   =>  'February',
        3   =>  'March',
        4   =>  'April',
        5   =>  'May',
        6   =>  'June',
        7   =>  'July',
        8   =>  'August',
        9   =>  'September',
        10  =>  'October',
        11  =>  'November',
        12  =>  'December'
    )

    return $months[$month];
}
```

Comment: i can do this , i asked , is there any PHP built in functions to do this

Answer (score 1):

```
$month  = 1; //month in numeric
echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10)); //print January
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a Unix time (in 1970) by multiplying the month number by the average number of seconds in a month (2628000) and taking away 15 days so it is always somewhere in the middle of the month. So this works nicely and avoids unnecessary overhead:

```
function month_name($i) {
    return date('F', $i * 2628000 - 1314000);
}
```

The actual dates (if you substitute 'd F Y' for 'F') vary from 16 January 1970 to 16 December 1970 for $i from 1 to 12. You can do a similar trick to get day names (with 1 - 7 giving Monday - Sunday):

```
function day_name($i) {
    return date('l', $i * 86400 + 302400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function mktime() which takes the date elements as parameters.

```
<?php
 $month_number= 3;
 $month_name = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_number, 10));
 echo $month_name; 
?>
```

Output:
**March**

In function mktime(), the parameters are hour,minute,second,month,day,year.

For more information, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php