# Month from number to letter php if

Tags: php, monthcalendar

I have month in a form

I'd like a php formula that do this

```
if month = 6 -> $month1='June' if month = 7 -> $month1='July' if month = 8 -> $month1='August' if month = 9 -> $month1='Septmber'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715442/is-there-a-way-to-get-month-name-by-giving-an-integer-value-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work:

```
$month = 5;
$monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));
echo $monthName;
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine!and if I like obtain the month not in english but in italiano form example not June but Giugno

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to PHP :)

```
$month_names = array (
    "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
    "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec");

$name = $month_name[$month-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the datetime object:

```
$month = 3;
$monthName = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $month)->format('F');
echo $monthName;
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine!and if I like obtain the month not in english but in italiano form example not June but Giugno

Answer (score 0):

```
function getName($monthNumber){
   return date("F", strtotime("2014-".$monthNumber."-1 12:00:00"));
}
$month = 8 ; // <-- or any number you want
echo getName($month);
```

#### Output : *August*